# Not able to auto scroll to that tab to view on screen which are created dynamically

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

//I have generated number of tabs dynamically like 30 tabs , also by default i have selected specific tab by index, But I am unable to auto scroll to that tab to view on screen

//Firstly I have called fragment by passing dates and respective data list to show

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CalenderFragmentPageAdapter(fragmentManager, MainActivity.this, Finaldates, ProductList));
```

// Then I have called which sets tab property by extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
public class CalenderFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList tabTitle;
Context context;
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> ProductList;
String finalDate;

public CalenderFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, ArrayList<String> str, ArrayList<Map<String, String>> ProductList) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    tabTitle = str;
    this.ProductList = ProductList;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

// called new  fragment for each generated tab

    return calenderFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabTitle.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

   //Title to show on tab

}
}
```

//then at last I have load the fragment for selected tab that I want
by

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(selectedTabPos);
```

//now I am able to select fragment for that tab by above method but not able to auto scroll the tabs for which I have set selectedTabPos

//Xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Please share XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `TabLayout` is not scrollable, you can add following line to your `TabLayout` in XML:

`app:tabMode="scrollable"`

Comment: I have tried that too but not working at every load,its randomly getting correct

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply horizontal scroll to it

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorMyGreen"/>
```

try this...

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mTablayout.getTabAt(position).select();
```